# JUnit testing / calling function few times

Tags: java, junit

I am extracting concept from a single page and that page is being used in different functions, so i have created a function that assigns the value if value hasn't been assigned yet.

```
public String text() {                               
    if (text.isPresent()) {                          
        return text.get();                           
    }                                                
    this.text = Optional.of(extractText(pdDocument));
    return text.get();                               
}
```

I would like to create a test that checks that the function is being called once and the context is shared between the functions that doing some functionality in the same context

Here is an example when text() is being called twice

```
private Optional<String> packingListNet() {           
    return locatePattern(text(), PACKING_LIST_NET);   
}  

private Optional<String> packingListNumber() {        
    return locatePattern(text(), PACKING_LIST_NUMBER);
}
```

Would be grateful for any information, thank you

Comment: Information with regard to what?  Thread safety should be a concern.  Not clear.

Comment: @duffymo how to approach such case and write a Junit test to it , my apology if its not clear , English inst  my first language

Comment: @duffymo I assume checking if methods are referring to the same reference(value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The technical answer: you could use a mocking library, such as PowerMockito, to create **mocked** instances of the Optional class. And when you have a mock object, you can instruct the mock how to react to method calls. Then you need to "get" the mocked Optional object into your class under test.

You could use that to cover the first if statement: you expect the mock to see the `isPresent()` call, to return true, and to then return a specific string. Your testcase could then check "that expected string came back". Similar for the other way round, when the mocked Optional "is empty", then you ensure another string is returned, and you check for that.

But honestly, it is doubtful if you should do that all.

You should focus on the public **contract** that your method there provides.

And that would mean:

- Enable yourself that you can pass in a (real) Optional object into the class under test
- When your Optional is not empty, your test expects ... what you put into it
- When your Optional is empty, your test expects whatever `extractText()` will return

Of course, mocking is really problematic here: Optional is a **final** class. So you need to either use Mockito with "experimental support for final enabled", or you need to use PowerMock(ito) (which I strongly advise to never use).

So, as said: avoid mocking.

Answer (score 2):

I think this method is badly conceived.  It may rely on private, mutable state that will be a problem with multiple documents and threads accessing them.

A better approach would be to pass all the necessary information as method parameters. They are thread safe that way;

```
public static String getText(String textToSearchFor, Document pdfDocument) {
    // extract here
}
```

Here's how I might write a JUnit test for a method like this:

```
public class TextMethodOwnerTest {

    @Test
    public void testGetText_Success() {
        // setup
        String expected = "text to find";
        Document pdf; // Have to get this.
        // exercise
        String actual = TextMethodOwner.getText(expected, pdf);
        // assert
       Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetText_PackingListNumber() {
        // Add another case here
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetText_PackingListNet() {
        // Add another case here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what are you trying to ask. Information is not clear but maybe this can help you:

**Junit and mockito are mostly used togther.** If you want to check any function gets called only one time we use verify() method of mockito with parameter atLeast(1)

For example: Example taken from (https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-verify)

```
List<String> mockedList = mock(MyList.class);
mockedList.clear();
mockedList.clear();
mockedList.clear();
verify(mockedList, atLeast(1)).clear();
```

Comment: Yikes. A generic answer ... that leaves out all the relevant aspects of the quesiton.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some pseudo code how you could achieve it:

```
public Class {
   int counter = 0;
   void test() {
      counter++;
   }
}

public ClassTest {

public Class class;

void shouldBeCalledOneTime() {
   class.test();
   AssertThat(class).hasFieldWithValue("counter", 1);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your question seemed to me mostly about **reading the file only once**, which is quite a genuine need for many, I wrote up this class using your code, but without JUnit.

This has a main method that calls the `packingList*()` method 100 times to different threads, but you will see that the extraction part is entered into only once in the beginning. For this, I have added a lock and used a `synchronized` block. I understand that this is basic, but thought I may share since it might help others.

Note the changes in the method `public String text()`.

```
public class ReusedText{
private static final long PACKING_LIST_NET = 200;
private static final long PACKING_LIST_NUMBER = 120;

private Optional<String> text = Optional.ofNullable( null );
private Document pdDocument;

private static final Object LOCK = new Object();
private static final ExecutorService svc = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 2 ); 

public ReusedText(Document pdDocument) {
    super();
    this.pdDocument = pdDocument;
}

public static void main( String[] args ){
    ReusedText rt = new ReusedText( new Document( "/path/to/document/on/disk" ) );

    for( int i = 0; i < 100; i++ ) {
        svc.submit( () -> System.out.println( rt.packingListNet() ) );
        svc.submit( () -> System.out.println( rt.packingListNumber() ) );
    }

    svc.shutdown();
}

public String text() {
    if (text.isPresent()) {                          
        return text.get();                           
    }
    else {
        synchronized (LOCK) {
            /* This repeated 'if' block is necessary because 'text' may have got populated while this thread was waiting for lock. */
            if (text.isPresent()) return text.get();  
            else{ 
                System.out.println( "Extracting text..." );
                this.text = Optional.of( extractText( pdDocument ) );
                return text.get();
            }
        }
    }
}

private String extractText( Document doc ) {
    //Read the file contents using some API like java.nio.file.Files or Apache Tika
    return "file contents here!";
}

private Optional<String> packingListNet() {           
    return locatePattern(text(), PACKING_LIST_NET);   
}  

private Optional<String> packingListNumber() {        
    return locatePattern(text(), PACKING_LIST_NUMBER);
}

private Optional<String> locatePattern( String text, long packingListNumber ){
    //Implement your logic with the text here.
    return Optional.of( String.valueOf( packingListNumber ) );
}

private static class Document{
    private String pathToText;

    public Document(String pathToText) {
        super();
        this.pathToText = pathToText;
    }

    public String getPathToText(){
        return pathToText;
    }
}
}
```